# Ignored and favorited tags in the case of multi-tagged questions

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

What happens if:

1. a question has multiple tags, only one of which is ignored? (I assume the question is treated as if it had just an ignored tag, so ignored)
2. a question has an ignored and a favorited tag? (I have no idea)

Comment: If it has a tag you ignored then you won't see it even if it does have a favourite tag as well. It's easy to check with questions with bounties on them. Like the number on the tab will be (5) but if you go in the bounties you may only see (3) questions because (2) of them included your ignored tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, ignored and favourited tags are handled entirely in the browser. You can either *hide* ignored tags, or you can choose to have them shown greyed out.

If you configured your account to *hide* ignored tags, then *any* ignored tag on a post will caused it to be removed from the view. The whole question will not be shown. It doesn't matter how many tags are hidden, nor if there is a favourite tag as well.

If you have opted to just grey out ignored tags, then the post is shown faded.
If a post has both an ignored *and* a favorited tag, it is shown with the yellow background *and* is faded:

> [image]

The above screenshot shows, in order, a post with an ignored tag, a post with an ignored *and* a favourite tag, a post with a favourite tag, and a post with neither.